# How to get the value from Login page to all other components in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, jwt

I have a login page built in react. When user get authenticated successfully, I will get an Auth jwt token response. I need that token on all other pages so that when other pages makes request to API I will send that in header of the request. How can I have token value accessible to other component as well. Kindly help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: In my opinion, you can use `context` in React if you are not using `Redux` store.

Comment: @SarthakAggarwal I am just started to work on PoC. If we want to use redux store that what is the approach for this. Also how can I use context for this scenario.